# Selecting and updating from multiple tables using arcpy.UpdateCursor()?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have two feature classes which have common Valve ID #s.  One table has multiple service connections with a unique number.  I need to select all services linked to each valve and collect the individual service # then update the service fields (1-4) in the Valve class with each connection #.

I believe I can do it with an updateCursor but I'm not a strong coder.

Answer (score 3):

```
    import arcpy, sys, string, os   
    valve = r"C:\valves.shp"
    services = r"C:\serviceConnectors.shp"
    fieldname1 = "ValveID"
    fieldname2 = "ConnectorServiceID"
    ucur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(valve)
    for urow in ucur:
        connectorlist = []
        valveid = ucur.GetValue(fieldname)
        sql = fieldname + " = " + valveid#This syntax probably won't work
        scur = arcpy.SearchCursor(services, sql)
        for srow in scur:
            connectorvalue = srow.GetValue(fieldname2)
            connectorlist.append(connectorvalue)
```

This should get you started.  You'll have to give more info on how you want the fields updated to add to the algorithm.